# Do you need a KafkaTemplate for each topic?

Tags: spring-kafka

Looks like KakfkaTemplate can be configured using generics to indicate the Key and a Value. Is the type of key specific for a use case? e.g. some identifying information like personId, patientId,  the value would present some sort of a pojo (DTO, probably not an entire JPA entity)

This leads to a question, should we configure multiple KafkaTemplates depending on use case (for each topic) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `KakfkaTemplate` is generic for coding convenience.
But if your different topics deals with different data types, you really should consider to have a separate type-safe `KakfkaTemplate` for that purpose.

Another note: the  `KakfkaTemplate` is fully based on the `KafkaProducer`, which requires particular `ProducerProperties` including `key/value` serializers.

So, yes, for different data types you need separate `KafkaProducer`s and, therefore, `KakfkaTemplate`. Even if they look into the same Kafka Broker.

Comment: Thank you both for answering.